# Add Toggle Buttons with if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, kivy, togglebutton

Based on an input (0, 1, 2 or 3) the kv.file or py.file should add a group of Toggle Buttons to the already existing layout. I tried a lot but can't seem to figure it out and would love some advice, since it is all still a bit new to me.

- So when self.reminder() = 0, no Toggle Buttons are shown.
- When self.reminder() = 1, one group of Toggle Buttons is shown.
- When self.reminder() = 2, two groups of Toggle Buttons are shown.
- When self.reminder() = 3, three groups of Toggle Buttons are shown.
- self.reminder() will not excess the value of 3.

So I have got my .py file

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
import csv
from kivy.core.window import Window

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

#Backgroundcolour
Window.clearcolor = (0.67, 0.83, 0.88, 1)

class DiaryToday(Screen):
    user_id = 3
    # reads how many reminders (aka Toggle Buttons) the user wants from csv file
    # used for textlabel, this textlabel will not show if reminder == 0 (is stated in kv file)
    def reminder(self):
        with open('users.csv') as file:                     #TO DO: needs to be adjusted to global ID
            reader = csv.DictReader(file)
            for row in reader:
                if row['id'] == str(self.user_id):          #TO DO: needs to be adjusted to global ID
                    if row['mood_rem'] == 'Zero':
                        return(0)
                    else:
                        return(row['mood_rem'][0])


    # TO DO: STORES in CSV file which emoji you clicked
    def mood_value(self, mood):
        print (mood)

    #Takes care of which group of ToggleButtons is shown in the Diary Screen
    def add(self):
        if root.reminder() == 0:
            #should add or show no Toggle Buttons
        if root.reminder() == 1:
            #should add or show 1 set of Toggle Buttons
        if root.reminder() == 2:
            #should add or show 2 sets of Toggle Buttons
        if root.reminder()== 3:
            #should add or show 3 sets of Toggle Buttons

class LoopApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return DiaryToday()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LoopApp().run()
```

And my .kv file

```
    
<DiaryToday>:

    name: "diarytoday"
    answer: answer
    diaryinput: diaryinput
    id: test

    FloatLayout:

        Button:
            background_color: 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 1
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.05, 'center_x': 0.5}
            font_size: 18
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.05
            text: "Save"

        Button:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.95, 'center_x': 0.175}
            background_color: 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 1
            font_size: 18
            size_hint: 0.15, 0.05
            text: "Previous day"

        Label:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.95, 'center_x': 0.5}
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.05
            color: 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 1
            text: 'date'
            font_size: 22

        Label:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.87, 'center_x': 0.5}
            font_size: 18
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.05
            color: 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 1
            text: 'Question'

        TextInput:
            font_size: 14
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.1
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.78, 'center_x': 0.5}
            id: answer

        Label:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.67, 'center_x': 0.5}
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.05
            color: 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 1
            font_size: 18
            text: 'My Diary'

        TextInput:
            font_size: 14
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.22
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.51, 'center_x': 0.5}
            id: diaryinput

        Label:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.36, 'center_x': 0.5}
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.05
            color: 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 1
            font_size: 18
            text: ' ' if root.reminder() == 0 else 'How are you feeling?'


        BoxLayout:
            id: ToggleButtonGroup1
            pos_hint: {'center_y':0.26, 'center_x': 0.5}
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            ToggleButton:
                background_normal: 'VerysadEmoji1.png'
                background_down: 'VerysadEmoji2.png'
                group: "emojis"
                size_hint: 0.5, 1.3
                on_press: root.mood_value(1)
            ToggleButton:
                background_normal: 'SadEmoji1.png'
                background_down: 'SadEmoji2.png'
                group: "emojis"
                size_hint: 0.5, 1.3
                on_press: root.mood_value(2)
            ToggleButton:
                background_normal: 'MediumEmoji1.png'
                background_down: 'MediumEmoji2.png'
                group: "emojis"
                size_hint: 0.5, 1.3
                on_press: root.mood_value(3)
            ToggleButton:
                background_normal: 'HappyEmoji1.png'
                background_down: 'HappyEmoji2.png'
                group: "emojis"
                size_hint: 0.5, 1.3
                on_press: root.mood_value(4)
            ToggleButton:
                background_normal: 'VeryHappyEmoji1.png'
                background_down: 'VeryHappyEmoji2.png'
                group: "emojis"
                size_hint: 0.5, 1.3
                on_press: root.mood_value(5)


        Label:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.19, 'center_x': 0.5}
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.05
            color: 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 1
            font_size: 18
            text: "Here will come Toggle Button Group 2"


        Label:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.12, 'center_x': 0.5}
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.05
            color: 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 1
            font_size: 18
            text: "Here will come Toggle Button Group 3"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class that is the Toggle Button Group that you want to add. Something like this:

```
class SomeToggles(BoxLayout):
    group = StringProperty('')  # this will be the group for the ToggleButtons
```

Then the `add()` method can be:

```
#Takes care of which group of ToggleButtons is shown in the Diary Screen
def add(self):
    if self.reminder() == 0:
        print('0')
        #should add or show no Toggle Buttons
    if self.reminder() == 1:
        print('1')
        self.ids.toggles.add_widget(SomeToggles(group=str(self.grp_count)))
        self.grp_count += 1
        #should add or show 1 set of Toggle Buttons
    if self.reminder() == 2:
        print('2')
        #should add or show 2 sets of Toggle Buttons
    if self.reminder()== 3:
        print('3')
        #should add or show 3 sets of Toggle Buttons
```

The above only handles the case where `self.reminder()` returns `1`, but the others would be similar. Of course, the `grp_count` (which is just a construct of mine to define the `group` property) needs to be added:

```
class DiaryToday(Screen):
    grp_count = 0
```

For this to work, a container with id of `toggles` must be defined. This will be another `BoxLayout` that contains the first set of Toggle Buttons as well as the added ones. So the modified `kv` file looks like:

```
<DiaryToday>:

    name: "diarytoday"
    answer: answer
    diaryinput: diaryinput
    id: test

    FloatLayout:

        Button:
            background_color: 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 1
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.05, 'center_x': 0.5}
            font_size: 18
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.05
            text: "Save"

        Button:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.95, 'center_x': 0.175}
            background_color: 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 1
            font_size: 18
            size_hint: 0.15, 0.05
            text: "Previous day"

        Label:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.95, 'center_x': 0.5}
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.05
            color: 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 1
            text: 'date'
            font_size: 22

        Label:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.87, 'center_x': 0.5}
            font_size: 18
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.05
            color: 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 1
            text: 'Question'

        TextInput:
            font_size: 14
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.1
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.78, 'center_x': 0.5}
            id: answer

        Label:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.67, 'center_x': 0.5}
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.05
            color: 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 1
            font_size: 18
            text: 'My Diary'

        TextInput:
            font_size: 14
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.22
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.51, 'center_x': 0.5}
            id: diaryinput

        Label:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.36, 'center_x': 0.5}
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.05
            color: 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 1
            font_size: 18
            text: ' ' if root.reminder() == 0 else 'How are you feeling?'

        BoxLayout:   # this contains all the Toggle Button groups
            id: toggles
            orientation: 'vertical'
            pos_hint: {'center_y':0.26, 'center_x': 0.5}
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            
            BoxLayout:
                id: ToggleButtonGroup1
                pos_hint: {'center_y':0.26, 'center_x': 0.5}
                size_hint: 0.5, None
                height: self.minimum_height
                ToggleButton:
                    background_normal: 'VerysadEmoji1.png'
                    background_down: 'VerysadEmoji2.png'
                    group: "emojis"
                    size_hint: 0.5, None
                    height: 40
                    on_press: root.mood_value(1)
                ToggleButton:
                    background_normal: 'SadEmoji1.png'
                    background_down: 'SadEmoji2.png'
                    group: "emojis"
                    size_hint: 0.5, None
                    height: 40
                    on_press: root.mood_value(2)
                ToggleButton:
                    background_normal: 'MediumEmoji1.png'
                    background_down: 'MediumEmoji2.png'
                    group: "emojis"
                    size_hint: 0.5, None
                    height: 40
                    on_press: root.mood_value(3)
                ToggleButton:
                    background_normal: 'HappyEmoji1.png'
                    background_down: 'HappyEmoji2.png'
                    group: "emojis"
                    size_hint: 0.5, None
                    height: 40
                    on_press: root.mood_value(4)
                ToggleButton:
                    background_normal: 'VeryHappyEmoji1.png'
                    background_down: 'VeryHappyEmoji2.png'
                    group: "emojis"
                    size_hint: 0.5, None
                    height: 40
                    on_press: root.mood_value(5)
<SomeToggles>:
    pos_hint: {'center_y':0.26, 'center_x': 0.5}
    size_hint: 0.5, None
    height: self.minimum_height
    ToggleButton:
        group: root.group
        size_hint: 0.5, None
        height: 40
    ToggleButton:
        group: root.group
        size_hint: 0.5, None
        height: 40
    ToggleButton:
        group: root.group
        size_hint: 0.5, None
        height: 40
```

The above `kv` also includes the `<SomeToggles>` rule that defines how the new Toggle Button group is built. You will also need to provide a mechanism for calling `self.reminder()`. I just added that call to the `mood_value()` method.